# intially select sw_front view controller swrevealviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller

I have two profile in my app. So after some initial profile setup, my app  will start with different screens (**firstVC** or **SecondVC**).
[image]

So based on the initial (Consider *Appdelegate :didfinish Method*) setup, i wish to select "**sw_front**" to be firstVC or secondVC.

Every time firstVC is *loaded first*. If i wish to open SecondVC first, i tried is very simlpe code in *viewWillAppear* Method, may be incorrect:

```
UIViewController * sec = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondID"];

UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sec];

[self.revealViewController pushFrontViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

The issue is app directly enters firstVC, but I want it to enter directly in FirstVC or SecondVC, when needed.
Thanks, any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you are coding wrong.Try below code when you are pushing.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = nil;
storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
SWRevealViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks @hari for answer, But Code i wrote above works well too.. Issue is, it first enters firstVC n then SecondVC. I want to directly enter SecondVC, when needed.

Comment: @nikdange_me- In this case you can take separate navigation controllers  for  two classes then it will work, My assumption if the flow if **Fitst view**--> **Second-view**, In this case second view dont have navigation, it will come based on first control,If i am wrong let me know

Comment: are you sure navigation controller would help??